# Add tag "series:" into Highcharts, from the response server JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, highcharts

I try to create a chart with Highcharts, but I can not fill the field "series" with the response returned from the server with PHP. The answer is in JSON format. The chart is not rendered, it goes white background. I pass the code and line of highchart JSON returned by the server. Thank you very much in advance. I am newbie, please have mercy.
I paste her the 2 codes:

SERVER SIDE PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla))
{
    $fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
    $hora = $row_RecordsetTabla['hora'];
    $estado = $row_RecordsetTabla['estado'];
    $arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y,m,d");
    $arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H,i");
    $arr[] = array("Date.UTC(".$arregloFecha.",".$arregloHora.")", $estado);
}
$arr2[] = array('data' => $arr);
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

RESPONSE SERVER JSON:

```
[{"data":[["Date.UTC(2014,03,27,12,00)","2"],["Date.UTC(2014,04,01,19,10)","1"],  ["Date.UTC(2014,04,01,15,44)","1"]]}]
```

CLIENT SIDE JAVASCRIPT HIGHCHARTS CODE:

```
$.get("mostrarStatsDispositivo.php", {idDispositivo:"2", numeroDispositivo:"hola"}, function(data){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {`enter code here`
            renderTo: 'divStatsDispositivo',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Gráfica de actividad'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,        
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                hour: '%H',
            }   
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: [ 'APAGADO', 'ACTIVO', 'ALARMA'],   
            title: {
                text: 'ESTADO'
            },
            min: 0
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'grafica',
            type : 'line',
            data : data,  //<--------- NOT WORKING?¿
        }]
    });
},"json");
```

....thanks!

Comment: there's a quote missing after `text: 'Gráfica de actividad`

Comment: yes! ...thanks! now i change!! that quickly ...! ...It was a mistake to copy/paste the code,  ...the problem still.... , but thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems going on:

- The data you want is `actually data[0].data`
- Your data is not string data but is wrapped in quotes.
- Highcharts expects datetime data to be ordered (yours is not).

When I change those things, it works:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [{"data":[[Date.UTC(2014,03,27,12,00),2],[Date.UTC(2014,04,01,15,44),1],  [Date.UTC(2014,04,01,19,10),1]]}],
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'divStatsDispositivo',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Gráfica de actividad'
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,        
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                hour: '%H',
            }   
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: [ 'APAGADO', 'ACTIVO', 'ALARMA'],   
            title: {
                text: 'ESTADO'
            },
            min: 0
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'grafica',
            type : 'line',
            data : data[0].data, 
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fUhEj/1/

Comment: Yeahh! Thank you very much for the reply. You're right, being quoted data, become a string. Now I'm trying to change the PHP file to the JSON string is formed without the quotes. If I do this, it should work? I am not sure how to change the file to modify lel PHP JSON returned. 
Thanks again, I'm tired of being a newbie, lol...  You are great!

Comment: ....sorry, i can´t vote up the answer... i don´t have minimun reputation....  .....tired of being newbie again.... :(

Comment: ...i added another post for my question, because the problem persist for another cause (i think..). the title is: "Insert tag “series:” into Highcharts, from the response server JSON. Malformed JSON?"

Comment: @xavi - You should be able to accept the answer (the checkmark). It ups your reputation to accept answers also.